# Is it possible to get command line arguments in logback.xml?

Tags: java, logback

I know we can get environment variables from `${...}` or get `${some.system.properties}` but how can we get the command line arguments in logback.xml

Comment: I think it is useful for you http://openwritings.net/content/public/excerpt/pass-variableparameter-logbackxml

Answer (score -1):

You can use `-Dfoo=bar` to provide environment variables *in* the command line, but otherwise logback doesn't have access to other arguments.